# Fetch data from database show in wordpress Dashboard

Tags: php, wordpress

I have created one menu in wordpress Dashboard using below code(taken from codex)

```
/** Step 2 (from text above). */
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'my_plugin_menu' );

/** Step 1. */
 function my_plugin_menu() {
add_menu_page( 'My Plugin Options', 'Personalization', 'manage_options', 'personalization-detail', 'my_plugin_options' );
}
```

Now I am able to get the current logged-in user information like this

```
function my_plugin_options() {
if ( !current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) )  {
    wp_die( __( 'You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page.' ) );
}
echo '<div class="wrap">';
 global $current_user;

  echo 'Username: ' . $current_user->user_login . "\n";
  echo 'User email: ' . $current_user->user_email . "\n";

echo '</div>';
```

}

But I want to fetch data from some other table.
**Note** I have placed all code within the functions.php

Comment: Do you want to get data from WordPress default tables or from the one which you created?

Comment: I am sorry for delay I want to fetch the data from which i have created

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the table which you have.

1. [Retrieve data from WordPress default data structure.](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference)
2. [Retrieve data from your custom table.](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb)

Here is an example for retrieving data from a custom table.

```
global $wpdb;
$table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'my_table';
$results = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare('SELECT * FROM '.$table_name ) );
if ( $results ) {
    foreach ( $results as $result ){
        //handle data
    }

}
```